# Adobe Acrobat JavaScript get date input to header

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I have a question.
We have a form we use as user agreement to sign for hardware.
The header is generated as following: `Agreement/name/equipment/ MM-YYYY`

The MM - YYYY is generated by:

```
var f = this.getField("Datum2");
f.value = util.printd("mm-yyyy", new Date());
```

This works great, but sometimes we make the agreements in advance for people that start in a new month but the date on top keeps showing the date on which we made the document.

What I want is that is shows the date we set in the document.
So I have a field called `date` where we pick the date. That's the month I want to see up top.

I've googled a lot and searched around here but I have no experience with JavaScript so I'm kind of lost now.